# Xamarin.Forms: Xam.Media.Plugin is not working on Android device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have using Xam.Media.Plugin in my xamarin.forms app.

After implementation, the capture & pick image functionality was working fine.
But now on Android device, capture & pick image is not working any more.
Android app is crashing.
On iPhone, its working fine.

Here is the output of android app crash:

```
09-21 21:26:53.005 D/Mono (15231): Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/guguus.guguus/files/.__override__/Plugin.Media.Abstractions.dll'.
09-21 21:26:53.006 D/Mono (15231): AOT: image '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/guguus.guguus/files/.__override__/Plugin.Media.Abstractions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/guguus.guguus-1/lib/x86/libaot-Plugin.Media.Abstractions.dll.so" not found
09-21 21:26:53.006 D/Mono (15231): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Plugin.Media.Abstractions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/guguus.guguus-1/lib/x86/libaot-Plugin.Media.Abstractions.dll.so" not found
09-21 21:26:53.007 D/Mono (15231): Assembly Ref addref guguus.Mobile.XamarinForm.Shared[0xaab44a60] -> Plugin.Media.Abstractions[0xaab43f80]: 2
```

Please help me to find out the reason of crash.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something with permissions, check twice: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!!!

It was because of other nuget packages.
I removed those packages & now it is working fine.

Comment: Which packages you removed, that caused the project to work?

Comment: I added some packages related to chart, In App purchases etc.